# Installing Debian applications on Linux Mint

Tags: ubuntu, installation, debian, linux-mint

I'm trying to install an application (Google Chat) and it gives me the option for Debian/Ubuntu with a `.deb` extension. So since I have Mint, I generally just do everything as if were Ubuntu.

So I downloaded the file and it has 4 folders;

- DEBIAN
- usr
- opt
- usr

I was told that it's supposed to be a one-click install. What am I doing wrong and how do I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be rather straightforward. You don't need to extract the `.deb` file. In a terminal, enter:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/name_of_file.deb
```

Replace the path to the actual path of your file.

Comment: I think it is better to suggest gdebi instead of dpkg -i because gdebi have a gui and it can resolve dependancies

Comment: Feel free to edit this answer.